# Import error: cannot import name 'ClientCredential' from 'office365.sharepoint.client_context'

Tags: python-3.x, sharepoint, office365-rest-client

I encountered this error in Python. When import office365.sharepoint.client_context, there is no error. But when doing from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientCredential, the error showed:

Import error: cannot import name 'ClientCredential' from 'office365.sharepoint.client_context'

Anyone know how to solve this issue? thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a little redundant and old question, but the ClientCredential should be imported from `runtime.auth.client_credential` instead of `sharepoint.client_context`.

i.e., the below works fine:

```py
from office365.runtime.auth.client_credential import ClientCredential
```